# Bad request instead of message

Tags: angular, error-handling, httpresponse, http-status-code-400, 400-bad-request

i hava a problem that i am unble to figure whats i am doing wrong.
So basically backend sends the error message but somehow browser is overwrites the message with Bad request.

[Screen shoot of message that browser retuens me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DteT.png)

[This is the response from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBhbp.png)

I want to know why my browser is giving me bad request instead of response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without to see your code I think you can solve the problem with the observe option inside the http request. The observe option gives you the full response.

[Angular Guide Http](https://angular.io/guide/http)

[image: HTTP Client observe]

Greetings, Flo

Comment: found it in there. it was a problem with the code. thanks a lot. it was returning status text instead error.message